# Perform calculation after adding Commas to the number

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which adds commas to the text field. Example: `5000000` is returned as `5,000,000`.

```js
function addComma(values) {
   values.value = values.value.replace(",", "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

if (document.getElementById("values"))
    payment = parseInt(document.getElementById("values").value);
```

```html
<label1>Rent</label1> <input id="values" type="text" onkeyup="addComma(this);">
```

However, I am not able to use it any further with other variables. If i remove `parseInt`, it returns  `NAN` and adding `parseInt` returns `5`.

```
payment = 10;
values = 5,000,000
```

The following returns `PV = payment * NAN5,000,000` while debugging.

```
PV = payment*values;
```

What am i doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: FYI: There is no such element as `<label1>`. There is `<label>`, but it requires that you either nest the form field that it is a label for within it or that you give the element a `for` attribute that has a value that is the `id` of the element that it is a label for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Comment: If I'm not mistaken about what you're asking, once you add the commas, it is no longer a number. It's a string. So any attempt to add, subtract, multiply, etc with another number will either result in NaN.

Comment: The best way to do something like this would be to do all the operations you are going to do on the number, and then format it with the commas.

Comment: Your input decorating function doesn't handle backspace very well.  Unless it's 100% flawless I think it's going to be a lot more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The questions are different. My question was not how but why i am  not able to perform further calculations after the 'how'.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Yes. I posted the answer. Changing it back to the number for further calculation worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get rid of commas by using the below command:

```
values = values.replace(/\,/g,'')
```

this essencially removed all the commas from your string
now, convert the string validly representing a number to a number indeed using:

```
values = Number(values)
```

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: What does this do? Why does it fix the issue? Please try to add a bit more detail; it's rare that *"Just do this"* is considered a "complete" and/or "good" answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `parseInt` on a string that has commas added.
`parseInt` will stop parsing after the first non-numeric character:

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

```js
console.log(parseInt('123456')); // 123456
console.log(parseInt('123,456')); // 123
```

Given this, you should remove the commas before parsing:

```js
function addComma(values) {
  values.value = values.value.replace(",", "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  
  // Moved the rest of the conde into the function so you can
  // see the output as you type.
  // Get your element by Id into a const so you don't need to query twice.
  const element = document.getElementById("values");
  if (element) {
    // Remove commas from the number to be parsed
    const value = element.value.replace(",", "");
    // It is best practice to include the radix when calling parseInt
    const payment = parseInt(value, 10);
    console.log(payment);
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Rent</label> <input id="values" type="text" onkeyup="addComma(this);">
```

Comment: Translating a string of comma seperated numbers is well within `parseInt`s usecase

Comment: nope, `parseInt` will stop parsing after finding the first comma, I'll add that to the answer,

Comment: @SpeedOfRound `parseInt()` stops parsing at the first non-numeric character. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt): *If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point.*

Comment: Be aware that, while not a requirement, it is a best-practice to include the optional second argument to `parseInt()`, which is the radix. This protects against base operations other than the intended base being accidentally performed.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following worked for me.

```
payment = document.getElementById("values").value;
var Return = payment.replace(/\,/g,'');
```

Instead of parseInt i just declared another variable and removes commas to perform any further calculations.